# How to strip backslashes when jQuery passes string to Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, jquery

We are trying to return user inputs as Json to the server to be saved in couchbase, but we are struggling to send back the valid Json to the server, it adds ( \ ) between " ".

The Json

```
 var fileToJS = {
         "FormName": "Form1",
         "FormBody": //Nested, complex json continued
    }
```

Here is the Jquery post:

```
$('.sendIt').click(function () {
        alert('sendIt')
        var back = JSON.stringify(fileToJS);
        var url = "../Home/updateFormSave";
        $.post(url, { jsonStuffs: back}, function (data) {
            alert('qq');
        });

});
```

The controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult updateFormSave(string jsonStuffs)
        {

            //Save to couchbase
            FormRepository formRep = new FormRepository();
            //string formIdAppended = formID + "-" + User.Identity.Name;
            JavaScriptSerializer invalidJson = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            dynamic validJson = invalidJson.DeserializeObject(jsonStuffs);

            bool JsonForm = formRep.SaveForm("12345", validJson );

            ViewBag.msg = jsonStuffs;
            return View("updateFormSavedSuccess");
        }
```

The post works but if we debug and look at jsonStuffs, it looks like this

```
{\"FormName\":\"Form1\"}
```

Please help, are we doing something wrong with the serialization?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're viewing the string whilst paused in the debugger which will escape the quotes `""` with a backslash `\`.

The actual json string will be:

> { "FormName" : "Form1" }

Print the value to a console window, it's fine.

Comment: That suggests you have other issues with your code. You should define `not working` and update your question with the relevant info. Didn't you say that the post works fine?

Comment: Yes the `post` works but it is not pulling back valid Json, please provide facts that sate the Json is still?

Comment: Have you printed the json that you pull back to a console window or log or are you still viewing it paused in the debugger?

Comment: Ill admit, my method in couchbase was incorrect, testing code edits

Comment: The web cosole prints normal json, but it still gives couchbase the invalid json

Answer (score 0):

Are you using JSON.stringify ?

I had

```
            var filename = "sample.txt"
            $.ajax({
                ...
                data: { "filename" : JSON.stringify(filename) },
                ...
            });
```

which resulted in \sample.txt\ in the controller.

I removed JSON.stringify

```
                data: { "filename" : filename },
```

which fixed the issue for me.